# Is PEX exposed to the environment OK to use?

Tags: plumbing, pex

In preparation for a big job I found some PEX on craigslist.

It appears to have been exposed to the elements but all in all it looks fine.

http://images.craigslist.org/00J0J_kqRj1PQAivO_600x450.jpg

Can PEX withstand a little environmental conditions without loosing it's stability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO.** PEX degrades in the presence of UV radiation. A few days exposure reduces its lifetime resistance to chlorine by 50%. Source: http://www.coengineers.com/preventable-problems-with-pex/

Comment: Got it. So pass on the deal?

Comment: Unless you want to rip it out and replace it in 12-20 years, I would pass. :) Then again, there's no way to know how much UV exposure PEX you buy in a store has had anyway...

Comment: I am doing this before I sell my house. I'll just get it at HD.

Comment: Also, it's fine if you have a whole-house filter that removes chlorine, as that's the oxidizing element in the water that degrades PEX; the sacrificial anti-oxidants in the plastic that protect against this are themselves degraded by UV radiation!

Comment: Cool. Yeah no filtering here. I'll just go to the big box.

Comment: Why do people do work before they sell their house?  They won't get to enjoy it, and they have no incentive to do it well.